# How to work with an ESRI projection in R using sf?

Tags: r, esri-geodatabase, sf, epsg, equal-earth-projection

I want to use the Africa Albers Equal Area Conic projection for some analyses on animal territories that span the African continent. https://epsg.io/102022

Unfortunately this has a ESRI code rather than EPSG. The latter play well with many functions in R but not the former.

How do I get around this?

E.g. in the following simple code, it'd be handy to plug in 102022 in place of 4326.

```
library(sf)
library(spData)

Kenya <- world[world$name_long == "Kenya", 0]
rpoints <- st_sample(Kenya, size = 100, type = "random", crs = st_crs(4326))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `st_crs("ESRI:102022")`:

```r
library(sf)
library(spData)

Kenya <- world[world$name_long == "Kenya", 0]

# Transform to ESRI:102022
Kenya_proj <- st_transform(Kenya,
  crs = st_crs("ESRI:102022")
)

# Sample
rpoints <- st_sample(Kenya,
  size = 100,
  type = "random",
  crs = st_crs("ESRI:102022")
)


# Double check
st_crs(Kenya_proj) == st_crs("ESRI:102022")
#> [1] TRUE

st_crs("ESRI:102022")
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: ESRI:102022 
#>   wkt:
#> PROJCRS["Africa_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",
#>     BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
#>         DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
#>             ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
#>                 LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
#>         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
#>     CONVERSION["Africa_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",
#>         METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
#>             ID["EPSG",9822]],
#>         PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",0,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>             ID["EPSG",8821]],
#>         PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",25,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>             ID["EPSG",8822]],
#>         PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",20,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>             ID["EPSG",8823]],
#>         PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",-23,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>             ID["EPSG",8824]],
#>         PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
#>             ID["EPSG",8826]],
#>         PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
#>             ID["EPSG",8827]]],
#>     CS[Cartesian,2],
#>         AXIS["(E)",east,
#>             ORDER[1],
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
#>         AXIS["(N)",north,
#>             ORDER[2],
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
#>     USAGE[
#>         SCOPE["Not known."],
#>         AREA["Africa"],
#>         BBOX[-35,-25,39,55]],
#>     ID["ESRI",102022]]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  Spanish_Spain.1252          
#>  ctype    Spanish_Spain.1252          
#>  tz       Europe/Paris                
#>  date     2022-01-19                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  ! package     * version date       lib source        
#>    assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    backports     1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  D class         7.3-19  2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    classInt      0.4-3   2020-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    cli           3.0.1   2021-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    codetools     0.2-18  2020-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    crayon        1.4.2   2021-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    DBI           1.1.1   2021-01-15 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    dplyr         1.0.7   2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    e1071         1.7-9   2021-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    fansi         0.5.0   2021-05-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    generics      0.1.1   2021-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    glue          1.6.0   2021-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  D KernSmooth    2.23-20 2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    knitr         1.37    2021-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    lattice       0.20-45 2021-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    pillar        1.6.4   2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    proxy         0.4-26  2021-06-07 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    R.cache       0.15.0  2021-04-30 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    R.methodsS3   1.8.1   2020-08-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    R.oo          1.24.0  2020-08-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    R.utils       2.11.0  2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    raster        3.5-9   2021-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    Rcpp          1.0.7   2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    rlang         0.4.12  2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    rmarkdown     2.11    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    s2            1.0.7   2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    sf          * 1.0-4   2021-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    sp            1.4-5   2021-01-10 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    spData      * 2.0.1   2021-10-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    styler        1.6.2   2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>    terra         1.4-22  2021-11-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    tibble        3.1.6   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    tidyselect    1.1.1   2021-04-30 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    units         0.7-2   2021-06-08 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    vctrs         0.3.8   2021-04-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    withr         2.4.2   2021-04-18 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    wk            0.5.0   2021-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    xfun          0.29    2021-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>    yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#> 
#>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the proj4 string

```
prj <- sf::st_crs("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") 

rpoints <- st_sample(Kenya, size = 100, type = "random", crs = prj)
```

Comment: Isn't the WKT form preferred over PROJ4 strings?

Comment: @Spacedman true but, this is a lazy approach. The `sf::st_crs` parses the PROJ4 string into a WKT format. If you look at the prj object it is in WKT.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeffrey. I only used that code as a simple example but it doesn't actually seem to make a difference to the data points when I try it `prj <- sf::st_crs("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") 
Kenya <- world[world$name_long == "Kenya", 0]
rpoints <- st_sample(Kenya, size = 100, type = "random", crs = prj)
rpoints

rpoints_2 <- st_sample(Kenya, size = 100, type = "random", crs = 4326)
rpoints_2
`

Comment: There are some projections that only have the WKT string but when I tried to substituted into a CRS object I get this error "Scale limits cannot be mapped onto spatial coordinates in `coord_sf()`."